# Set different permissions on different branches of TFS 2013 project

Tags: git, tfs

i have a project on TFS which has 3 branches. (Main-branch, Integration-Branch and Dev-Branch)

i have three teams created. (dev-team,Integration-team and Admin-team)

1) what i want is that admin-team should have access on all three branches.
2) Integration-Team should have access on Dev-Branch and Integration-Branch.
3) Dev-team should only have access on Dev-Brach.

if i add all the teams to contributors group. All members get access to all branches.

if i remove teams from contributor list and directly add teams in version control. branch access sets well but no one gets access to (user stories, code reviews etc).

What should i do? Please suggest.

Also is there any easy way to set permissions? some tools etc?

i am using TFS web Access to manage permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting permissions on branches can be done through the Code tab of Web Access. When right-clicking on a branch, you can select security. Here you can add users and groups and then set the permissions to allow or deny.

What you can do is leave the security settings for the Dev-branch at default. This will grant everyone in the contributor group access.

For the main and integration branch you should remove the Contributor group (or set them at read only) and then add the Integration and Admin teams to them. The Integration team should have the Merge permissions set to Allow. The Admin group will probably have everything set to Allow.

Comment: if i remove contributor group, user don't get access to user stories and code review etc. how can i set contributor group to read only?

Comment: Read only for source code. User stories are not controlled trough the code security settings.